# Word that describes a repeating pattern across orders of magnitude of scale

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What word describes the notion of a simple pattern repeating itself across a multitude of scales?

For example, consider Gravity. The forces of gravity are present at the quantum scale (atoms attract each other). By combining these particles, we can go all the way to a cosmic scale, and the forces of gravity are ever-present amongst planets, galaxies, galactic clusters and onwards.

Richard Feynman described this notion beautifully when he said "Nature uses only the longest threads to weave her patterns, *so that each small piece of her fabric reveals the organization of the entire tapestry*."

Is there a word (or phrase) that describes the italicized part?

Comment: The term "tiling" is used in mathematics/physics to discuss patterns that repeat.  And, just as an aside, you might want to look at "Penrose tiles" -- likely not what you're after, but very interesting.

Comment: I'm not a physicist but I'm pretty sure the forces that hold atoms together are not called "gravity". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_interaction#The_interactions

Comment: Amazing question. Amazing. "scalability" and "fractals" jump to mind but do not really answer it. (As usual, I am out of votes at the time i want to give ten votes)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds to me like you are looking for [scale invariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_invariance):

> a feature of objects or laws that does not change if scales of length, energy, or other variables, are multiplied by a common factor.

Fractals are a well-known example of scale invariance:  if you zoom in to a tiny portion of the fractal image, you will get a similar picture to what you see when looking at the entire image.

The terms *[self-similar](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self-similar)*, *[recursive](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/recursive)*, and *[fractal](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fractal)* are also closely related.

Comment: Also _recursive, self-similar,_ and -- the extreme case -- _fractal_.

Comment: Excellent suggestions, @JohnLawler, I will incorporate them.  :-)

Comment: +1 for fractal.  I'm pretty sure that should be the actual answer.

Comment: Great suggestions! 'Fractal' nails the concept, and if there are no other responses, I will accept it as the answer tomorrow. Fractal (and recursive), seem to describe the concept from a top-down vantage point, as if going from a large scale to small scale. Is there a different word to describe a repeating pattern viewed from a bottom-up approach?

Answer (score 2):

You might consider ***holographic***.

> [***holography***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/holography) *- the art or process of making or using a **hologram***
>   ...taking note that...
>    [*Every part of a **hologram** contains the image of the **whole** object.*](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/optmod/holog.html#c4)